# How to filter customer Group by customer id

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, filter, customer-group

I need to get customer group for each customer in my site. I can get customer group list as below,

```
$customerGroupsCollection = $objectManager>get('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection');
$customerGroups = $customerGroupsCollection->toOptionArray();
foreach ($customerGroups as $key => $value) {
//print_r($value);
echo $value['label'];
}
```

How can I filter this by customer Id? I cannot use CustomerSession to get customer information since I need to retrieve each and every customer's data whenever needed.

I got customer data as follows,

```
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($customer as $cusitem) {
$customerId = $cusitem->getData('entity_id');
}
```

How can I combine these two and get customer group for each customer?

**Ex:**

*Have 10 customers(1-10), and have 3 customer groups (A,B,C). 
How to get each customer's group name?*

*if customer is 1, How to get 1's group?*

Comment: try to get customer ID and then try to get customer group ID.

Comment: Yes as @Lasantha said get customer id and then get group id check my answer

Comment: @gazorysu let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1):

**By Object Manager:**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$customers = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
$groupRepository  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface');

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $customerId = $customer->getEntityId(); // Get customer Id
    $groupId = $customer->getGroupId(); // Get customer group Id
    $group = $groupRepository->getById($groupId); // Get customer group data

    echo $groupCode = $group->getCode(); //Get Customer Group
}
```

**By Factory Method:**

```
protected $groupRepository;

protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
}

public function getCustomerCollection()
{   
    return $this->_customerFactory->create();
}

public function getGroupNameById($groupId){
    $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($groupId);
    return $group->getCode();
}
```

Now use this function in phtml file

```
$customers = $block->getCustomerCollection();

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    echo $customerId = $customer->getEntityId(); // Get customer Id
    $groupId = $customer->getGroupId(); // Get customer group Id
    echo $block->getGroupNameById($groupId);
}
```